# VBA get charts horizontal axis name / title

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[image: Chart Image]

I'm trying to write code to extract the **Horizontal Category Axis Labels** which is "`Member Share (p=30070)`" here. The whole thing is a part of a power point slide.

```
Function GetShapeDetails(pptshp As PowerPoint.Shape)
  Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim txt As String
  If pptshp.HasTextFrame Then txt = pptshp.TextFrame.TextRange

  Debug.Print "Shape Name - " & pptshp.Name & " / Shape Type - " & pptshp.Type & " / Text - " + txt

  If pptshp.Type = msoGroup Then
    For Each shp In pptshp.GroupItems
      GetShapeDetails shp
    Next shp
  End If


If pptshp.Type = msoTable Then

If pptshp.HasTable Then
Debug.Print "*** Table Details Start ***"
Debug.Print "Table Rows count -  " & pptshp.Table.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To pptshp.Table.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To pptshp.Table.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print pptshp.Table.cell(i,    j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next j
Next i
Debug.Print "*** Table Details End ***"
End If

End If


If pptshp.Type = msoChart Then

If pptshp.HasChart Then
Debug.Print "*** Chart Details Start ***"

        For Each sc In pptshp.Chart.SeriesCollection
            For Each d In sc.DataLabels
            Debug.Print d.Text
            Next
        Next

        With pptshp.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
         If .HasTitle Then Debug.Print .AxisTitle.Characters.Text
        End With

        With pptshp.Chart.Axes(xlValues, xlPrimary)
         If .HasTitle Then Debug.Print .AxisTitle.Characters.Text
        End With

Debug.Print "*** Chart Details End ***"
End If

End If

End Function
```

All of the above function work except for the part where it reads the chart data. this isn't fetching the Horizontal Category Axis Label. Please could anyone assist me here.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: @TimWilliams It gives me an error

Comment: In that case what is the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.Print "xlcategory Title -  " & pptshp.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary) _
    .HasTitle & pptshp.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text
```

If there is no title then you'll get an error when trying to access its Text.  Try this instead:

```
With pptshp.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary) _
     If .HasTitle Then Debug.Print .AxisTitle.Characters.Text
End With
```

Are you maybe using `&` as a logical operator here?  You can't do that in VBA.

Comment: I'm using & as a concatenation operator. Anyways, my requirement is to extract the text that can be found next to the golden star in the image which is "Member Share" in this case.

Comment: I gave your code a try and it gave me an automation error (unspecified error)

Comment: Can you read any properties from the chart at all?  You haven't posted much code so it's difficult to know what else might be going on.